# How to tell git to use the correct identity (name and email) for a given project?

Tags: git, github, gitolite, git-config

I use my personal laptop for both work and personal projects and I would like to use my work email address for my commits at work (gitolite) and my personal email address for the rest (github).

I read about the following solutions which are all either global or temporary:

- `git config --global user.email "bob@example.com"`
- `git config user.email "bob@example.com"`
- `git commit --author "Bob <bob@example.com>"`
- setting one of the `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`, `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` or `EMAIL` environment variables

One solution is to run manually a shell function that sets my environment to *work* or *personal*, but I am pretty sure that I will often forget to switch to the correct identity resulting in committing under the wrong identity.

Is there a way of binding a certain repository, project name, etc. to an identity (name, email)? What do people do?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

`git config user.email "bob@example.com"`

Doing that one inside a repo will set the configuration on THAT repo, and not globally.

Seems like that's pretty much what you're after, unless I'm misreading you.

Comment: I guess that should do it. I am expecting to have multiple local repositories for the same project, notably in order to switch between branches more easily without having to recompile everything. Maybe it's just a bad svn habit. Thanks.

Comment: @Martin--I haven't been using git real long, but the sense I get is that using multiple local repos would be an unusual workflow for git. Even so, you'd only need to run this once on an instance of the repo, and it's set for the lifespan of that repo, so it's not so bad.

Comment: @DanRay It is in fact a common setup if, as in Martin case, the local repo has local uncommitted files. Switching from one branch to another would not automatically rebuild files. If avoiding "to recompile everything" is a goal, using multiple local repos is the correct way to do it.

Comment: git config --global user.email "bob@example.com"   Adding the --global make it work across all repos.  source: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/

Comment: This is a manual task and may be forgotten. Automatic solutions are suggested by **@dragon788** and me

Comment: i've done this but git appears to ignore the local setting

Comment: Just to add that if you are still stuck with an old git version and you can't use @dragon788 answer, if your version is > 2.6.7, you can use worktree to do multiple checkout without having to config each one.

Answer (score 84):

You need to use the **local set** command below:

**local set**

```
git config user.email mahmoud@company.ccc
git config user.name 'Mahmoud Zalt'
```

**local get**

```
git config --get user.email
git config --get user.name
```

The local config file is in the project directory: `.git/config`.

**global set**

```
git config --global user.email mahmoud@zalt.me
git config --global user.name 'Mahmoud Zalt'
```

**global get**

```
git config --global --get user.email
git config --global --get user.name
```

The global config file in in your home directory: `~/.gitconfig`.

Remember to quote blanks, etc, for example: 'FirstName LastName'

Comment: amazing answer... i wish to keep local different from global

Answer (score 26):

Edit the config file with in ".git" folder to maintain the different username and email depends upon the repository

- Go to Your repository
- Show the hidden files and go to ".git" folder
- Find the "config" file
- Add the below lines at EOF

> [user]
>
> name = Bob
>
> email = bob@example.com

This below command show you which username and email set for this repository.

> git config --get user.name
>
> git config --get user.email

Example: for mine that config file in D:\workspace\eclipse\ipchat\.git\config

Here ipchat is my repo name

Answer (score 17):

If you use `git config user.email "foo@example.com"` it will be bound to the current project you are in.

That is what I do for my projects.  I set the appropriate identity when I clone/init the repo.  It is not fool-proof (if you forget and push before you figure it out you are hosed) but it is about as good as you can get without the ability to say `git config --global user.email 'ILLEGAL_VALUE'`

Actually, you can make an illegal value.  Set your `git config --global user.name $(perl -e 'print "x"x968;')`

Then if you forget to set your non-global values you will get an error message.

[EDIT]
On a different system I had to increase the number of x to 968 to get it to fail with "fatal: Impossibly long personal identifier".  Same version of git.  Strange.

Comment: It sounds like a great trick but it didn't work for me. Both commit and push to gitolite remote were successful.

Comment: @Martin Jambon: Strange.  I'm using git version 1.7.4.5

Comment: @Martin Jambon: You can also try setting your global username/email address to "x".  Some older versions of git rejected too small values.  Report what git version/os you have if this does not work.

Comment: @Martin Jambon: Try 968 "x" and see if that works better for you.

Answer (score 12):

As of Git 2.13 you can use an `includeIf` in your gitconfig to include a file with a different configuration based on the path of the repository where you are running your git commands.

Since a new enough Git comes with Ubuntu 18.04 I've been using this in my `~/.gitconfig` quite happily.

```
[include]
  path = ~/.gitconfig.alias # I like to keep global aliases separate
  path = ~/.gitconfig.defaultusername # can maybe leave values unset/empty to get warned if a below path didn't match
# If using multiple identities can use per path user/email
# The trailing / is VERY important, git won't apply the config to subdirectories without it
[includeIf "gitdir:~/projects/azure/"]
  path = ~/.gitconfig.azure # user.name and user.email for Azure
[includeIf "gitdir:~/projects/gitlab/"]
  path = ~/.gitconfig.gitlab # user.name and user.email for GitLab
[includeIf "gitdir:~/projects/foss/"]
  path = ~/.gitconfig.github # user.name and user.email for GitHub
```

https://motowilliams.com/conditional-includes-for-git-config#disqus_thread

To use Git 2.13 you will either need to add a PPA (Ubuntu older than 18.04/Debian) or download the binaries and install (Windows/other Linux).

Comment: Very helpful and exactly what I was looking for. Combined with `git config core.sshCommand` for multiple private keys, gives complete seamless git identity management.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't use the `--global` parameter it will set the variables for the current project only.

Answer (score 3):

I very like the way of Micah Henning in his article (see [Setting Up Git Identities](https://www.micah.soy/posts/setting-up-git-identities/)) on this subject.  The fact that he apply and force the identity to each repository created/cloned is a good way not to forget to set this up each time.

### Basic git configuration

Unset current user config in git:

```
$ git config --global --unset user.name
$ git config --global --unset user.email
$ git config --global --unset user.signingkey
```

Force identity configuration on each new local repository:

```
$ git config --global user.useConfigOnly true
```

Create Git alias for `identity` command, we will use later:

```
$ git config --global alias.identity '! git config user.name "$(git config user.$1.name)"; git config user.email "$(git config user.$1.email)"; git config user.signingkey "$(git config user.$1.signingkey)"; :'
```

### Identities creation

Create an identity with GPG (use `gpg` or `gpg2` depending on what you got on your system).  Repeat next steps for each identities you want to use.

> Note: `[keyid]` here is the *identifier* of created secret key.
>   Example here:
>
> ```
> sec   rsa4096/8A5C011E4CE081A5 2020-06-09 [SC] [expires: 2021-06-09]
>       CCC470AE787C057557F421488C4C951E4CE081A5
> uid                 [ultimate] Your Name <youremail@domain>
> ssb   rsa4096/1EA965889861C1C0 2020-06-09 [E] [expires: 2021-06-09]
> ```
>
> The `8A5C011E4CE081A5` part after `sec  rsa4096/` is the *identifier* of key.

```
$ gpg --full-gen-key
$ gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG <youremail@domain>
$ gpg --armor --export [keyid]
```

Copy the public key block and add it to your GitHub/GitProviderOfChoice settings as a GPG key.

Add identity to Git config.  Also repeat this for each identity you want to add:

> Note: here I use `gitlab` to *name* my identity, but from your question it can be anything, ex: `gitolite` or `github`, `work`, etc.

```
$ git config --global user.gitlab.name "Your Name"
$ git config --global user.gitlab.email "youremail@domain"
$ git config --global user.gitlab.signingkey [keyid]
```

### Setup identity for a repository

If a new repo has no identity associated, an error will appear on commit, reminding you to set it.

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

## parts of message skipped ##

fatal: no email was given and auto-detection is disabled
```

Specify the identity you want on a new repository:

```
$ git identity gitlab
```

You're now ready to commit with the *gitlab* identity.

Comment: It's worth mentioning than `git identity` is not a valid git command. I think your answer is inspired by [this article](https://www.micah.soy/posts/setting-up-git-identities/) which is great. Thank you

Comment: Yes, source is mentioned in the post :)

Answer (score 0):

> One solution is to run manually a shell function that sets my environment to work or personal, but I am pretty sure that I will often forget to switch to the correct identity resulting in committing under the wrong identity.

That was exactly my problem. I have written a hook script which warns you if you have any github remote and **not** defined a local username.

Here's how you set it up:

1. Create a directory to hold the global hook

   `mkdir -p ~/.git-templates/hooks`
2. Tell git to copy everything in `~/.git-templates` to your per-project `.git` directory when you run *git init* or *clone*

   `git config --global init.templatedir '~/.git-templates'`
3. And now copy the following lines to `~/.git-templates/hooks/pre-commit` and make the file executable (don't forget this otherwise git won't execute it!)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

RED='\033[0;31m' # red color
NC='\033[0m' # no color

GITHUB_REMOTE=$(git remote -v | grep github.com)
LOCAL_USERNAME=$(git config --local user.name)

if [ -n "$GITHUB_REMOTE" ] && [ -z "$LOCAL_USERNAME" ]; then
    printf "\n${RED}ATTENTION: At least one Github remote repository is configured, but no local username. "
    printf "Please define a local username that matches your Github account.${NC} [pre-commit hook]\n\n"
    exit 1
fi
```

If you use other hosts for your private repositories you have to replace `github.com` according to your needs.

Now every time you do a `git init` or `git clone` git will copy this script to the repository and executes it before any commit is done. If you have not set a local username it will output a warning and won't let you commit.