# Setting up Git User Name

Tags: git

I’m following the instructions to setup Git at 
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

The document states to run the following from the command line:

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

When I run these commands with the `$` sign in front I receive this error:

```
 $git is not re-cognized as an internal or external command.
```

I also tried:

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

When I run both lines the command line returns to the next line without an acknowledgement statement.

Afterwards the two commands do not seem to take effect.

I have Git with GitBash install.  Is there something obvious I am missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell git to use the correct identity (name and email) for a given project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116548/how-to-tell-git-to-use-the-correct-identity-name-and-email-for-a-given-project)

Answer (score 4):

`$` stands for "[prompt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt)". You should'nt *actually* write it; its only purpose is to indicate where to begin the command.

You should write them separately.

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
```

(Press enter) then

```
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```