# Change git username

Tags: git, android-studio, github, git-bash

I played with git bash few months ago  and I don't know how I accidentally set my name to "Your-Name"( =/ ).

Now every time I commit a change to my repos, It's show that "your-name" commit a change.

BTW - If i create a repo through android studio, It show like My actual username created the repo, but if I commit any changes and push It shows like "Your-Name" commited the changes.

How can I fix this and change to my actual github username?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting up Git User Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41002414/setting-up-git-user-name)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see your configuration information like below. [Refer to Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup)

```
$ git config --list
user.name=John Doe
user.email=johndoe@example.com
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=auto
color.diff=auto
...
```

Configuration information your user name, email

```
$ git config user.name
$ git config user.email
```

For changing your settings globally, across all repos:

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

For changing your settings only to current repo:

```
$ git config --local user.name "John Doe"  #if you omit --local also, by default it is local
$ git config --local user.email johndoe@example.com #if you omit --local also, by default it is local
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup), open a git bash prompt an run:

```
$ git config --global user.name "First Last"
```