# I have some problem on uploading Android project to my Github repo

Tags: android, github

i have some problem on uploading my Android project to Github repo.

The problem is that I can't add my 'manifests', 'src/drawable', 'src/layout', 'src/value' folders(that have *.xml files in common).

I already checked my .gitignore file and tried to push using Android Studio(VCS), terminal command, etc.

here's my .gitignore file.

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/libraries
/.idea/modules.xml
/.idea/workspace.xml
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
.externalNativeBuild
```

Thanks!

- here's the 'Add File For Initial Commit'
  [image: Add File For Initial Commit]
- and also the terminal command screenshot
  [image: terminal command screenshot]

Comment: May be you didn't add them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the reason via `git check-ignore -v <FLIE_NAME>`

Here's the result of questioner's.
In his case, `~/.gitignore_global` causes the problem.

```sh
$ git check-ignore -v colors.xml
> ~/.gitignore_global:4:*.xml colors.xml

$ cat ~/.gitignore_global
> *~
> .DS_Store
> Project_Default.xml
> *.xml
> venv
> build_file_checksums.ser
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you first create the `git` file using

```
git init
```

Then you add the whole project to it

```
git add .
```

You can check if there's something missing using

```
git status
```

If there's everything you can commit

```
git commit -m "First commit"
```

Add the remote repo to your project using

```
git remote add origin yourProject.git
```

And then push it to your repo

```
git push -u origin master
```

And if you need to setup your user and password (if it's your first time) here's an example to how to do it [Set user and password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33024593/4385913)

Try to re-install Android studio again because it seems that is problem with your Android Studio internal configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.(Especially thanks to KUJYP)

I had .gitignore-global file on my parent folder.

and it was

```
*~
.DS_Store
Project_Default.xml
*.xml
venv
build_file_checksums.ser
```

so i deleted that '*.xml' and it worked!

thanks to 'Skizo-ozᴉʞS' for helping me out and KUJYP!!

have a good day!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g8IP.png)

Comment: also check out this link :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144633/explain-which-gitignore-rule-is-ignoring-my-file